# Parse error while

Tags: php

Hello im getting an PHP Error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE) in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 32" any ideas on what im doing wrong?

```
<?php 
include ('includes/db_connect.php');
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT post_id, title, body FROM posts");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $body);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></head>script>
<![endif]-->
<script scr="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    #container{
        margin:auto;
        width:800px;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <?php
        while($query->fetch());
    ?>
    <article>
        <h2><?php echo $title ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $body?></p>
    </article>
    <?php endwhile?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

change: `while($query->fetch());`

to: `while($query->fetch()):`

(semi-colon to colon)